# who is this inside a lambda expression when implementing SAM?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, interface, this, sam

I have the following interface (SAM):

```
  fun interface  WebResponseHandler
{
    fun onWebResponseFinished(jsonString:String?)
}
```

and Inside a class, (lets call the class **ClassA**) i wrote the following code:

```
 private val onInitWebResponseHandler: VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler = VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler()
{
    Thread(ParseJsonStringOnInit(WeakReference(this),
            weakRefIOnAllScoresDataFirstFetched, it)).start()

}
```

i can't understand why in the first argument of *ParseJsonStringOnInit*, **this** is considered as **ClassA** and not as **VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler**?
Is this a convention when using **SAM**?

Comment: Why would you expect that? after all this is just a syntactic sugar for creating a class that implements an interface and has nothing to do with SAM.

Comment: Lambdas don't have a `this` unless there is a receiver parameter. If you need to refer to the anonymous class, you can't use the lambda syntax.

Comment: So to what `this` refer in this situation? Since code compiles and according to what i see (not  sure) it refer to the class that contains this piece of code

Comment: It refers to the nearest valid containing scope, which would be the class this property is defined in. You can ctrl+click it and the IDE will jump the cursor to what it refers to.

Comment: @Tenfour04, in SAM, the lambda expression will never have a receiver. Am i right?

Comment: I can't think of how it could ever have a receiver.